# Add date to git commit message automatically

Tags: linux, git, bash

so I have an sh script that throws together some files then commits them to a git repo.  How can I dynamically add the date to my commit message?

My .sh looks something like

```
// do things to files...
git add -u;
git commit -m 'generated files on <date here?>';
git push origin master;
```

Comment: The date is already included in the `git log`...is it really worth repeating in the message?

Comment: True, but it's nice to have it front and center.  I also want it to use server time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just format the output of the [date](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?date+1+NetBSD-current) command and Bob's your uncle:

```
// do things to files...
git add -u;
git commit -m "generated files on `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`";
git push origin master
```

Comment: This added the entire string, including the ticks

Comment: My apologies for the quote issue. Mistyped.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for the alias that I created (which I talk about at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64823742/470749): `function stpu() {
      git stash push -u -m "\`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\` ${@}"
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `prepare-commit-msg` or `commit-msg` [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)? You can find stubs in your `.git/hooks` directory.

Comment: Best answer imo.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd do that since commits are already timestamped, but something like:

```
THEDATE=`date`
git commit -m "... $THEDATE"
```

would do so. Note that the double-quotes are important.